# Regex: delete all html tags from html tags, except some other html tags

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I need to delete all html tags, such as `<p style="text-align: center;">` , but except `</em>` and `</em>` from the html tag  `<p class="glovo"></p>`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<p class="glovo">In these <p style="text-align: center;"> situations we may be forgetting to really <em>bend</em> at our practice and <em>sweat</em> at it.</p>
```

**MUST BECOME:**

```
<p class="glovo">In these situations we may be forgetting to really <em>bend</em> at our practice and <em>sweat</em> at it.</p>
```

**I use this GENERIC formula:**

`REGION-START(?=(?:(?!REGION-FINAL).)*?FIND REGEX)(?=(?:(?!REGION-FINAL).)).+?REGION-FINAL\R?`

```
REGION-START = <p class="glovo">
REGION-FINAL = </p>
FIND REGEX = <(?!/)[^>]*[^/]>(?!<em>|</em>)
```

**So, my final regex becomes:**

```
FIND:

<p class="glovo">(?=(?:(?!</p>).)*?<(?!/)[^>]*[^/]>(?!<em>|</em>))(?=(?:(?!</p>).)).+?</p>\R?

REPLACE BY: (LEAVE EMPTY)
```

The problem is that my regex selects THE ENTIRE html tag, not just the tags inside it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p class="glovo">|\G).*?\K<(?!/?em>).*?>(?=.*</p>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    <p class="glovo">       # literally
  |                       # OR
    \G                      # restart from last match position
)                       # end group
.*?                     # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
<                       # literally <
    (?!/?em>)               # not followed by em or /em
    .*?                     # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    >
(?=.*</p>)              # positive lookahead, make sure we have </p> somewhere after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but your regex has a little bug. After REPLACE, the final tag `</p>` is also delete. Must not be deleted

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: True. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. But what exactly means `(?:`  # non capture group  When is it used?

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: `(?:....)` is a non capture group. It means we want to group some part of the string, but the capture is useless because we don't reuse it after. It's very much more efficient than a capture group.